# A question which is to be proved assuming Bertrand Postulate

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I am trying  exercise problem of David Burton Elementary Number Theory and I am unable to think about this problem.

> Problem is->Prove that for every n$\geq$ 2 there exists a prime p with p$\leq$n< 2p .

Can someone please help how to think about this problem. 
I shall be really thankful.

Comment: Did you try to do an internet search for "proof of Bertrand's postulate"? It gives several useful results.

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020)'s a tutorial and reference for typesetting math on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Bertrand’s postulate, there is a prime $p$ with $k\lt p\lt2k$ for all integers $k\gt1$. Apply this for $k=\left\lceil\frac n2\right\rceil$ to obtain a prime $p$ with $\left\lceil\frac n2\right\rceil\lt p\lt2\left\lceil\frac n2\right\rceil$ and thus $\frac n2\lt p\le n$. Now multiply the left inequality by $2$ and move it to the right.

(This proof doesn’t apply for $n=2$, since in that case $\left\lceil\frac n2\right\rceil=1$, so we have to check separately that there is a prime $p=2$ such that $p\le2\lt2p$.)

Answer (score -1):

Assuming $n>2$ is non prime, now take the nearest prime (smaller than) $p$ of $n$, we can't have $p<2p\leq n$ because that would imply there is a prime $q$ such that $p<q<2p\leq n$ .(bertrand) contradicting the assumption that $p$ is the nearest prime. so the exact inequality is : $p<n<2p$.(why $n\neq 2p ?$) for $n$ is prime, thats an easy task.

Comment: No, this inequality doesn't hold for $n=2$; there is no prime $p$ such that $p\lt2\lt2p$. (In fact there isn't even such an integer.)

Comment: except that case only, now edited. Fixed.

Comment: also see that I said "non-prime" so you can not assume $n=2$.

Comment: I wasn't worried so much about the details of the proof as about your formulation "so the exact inequality is:" – this seemed to imply a correction of the (presumably inexact) inequality in the question, whereas in fact it's the inequality in the question that's exact.